# Using xampp as a web server

Tags: php, webserver, xampp, router

I'm currently working on a website on my local machine using xampp, I would like to share a demo of the site to a few people, before i move it into production, but im having issues, firstly i am behind a routers, so what I did is setup port forwarding so that my Wan IP would forward to my machines IP on ports 80 and 443, But others still get timeout issues, is there any suggestions, if it helps any I'm am running an older Belkin wireless router,

```
Firmware Version    9.01.07
Boot Version    0.01
Hardware    01
Serial No.  BE701195946
```

are there other win7/router/xmapp settings i could have missed?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you modify your OS's firewall settings? That may be blocking it. Still better is to get a web hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a matter of router settings if some get timeouts and others do not.  Rather, your upstream bandwidth might simply be too narrow to accept a lot of web traffic if you are attempting this on a residential ISP connection.  Remember, download for your HTTP visitors means upload for your router and cable/dsl modem.

If I misunderstand, and everyone is timing out, then you may not have ports 80 & 443 opened up in the Windows firewall.

Comment: I haven't been able to get anyone to see it, And I have completely disabled my firewall, and still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall? It might be blocking. Many routers have firewall nowadays...

Also did you check your router logs? Your web server must have a log too somewhere...

Comment: I tried once with no windows firewall, i looked at the router logs and didnt see my friends ip, I hadn't thought about looking for xampp, logs that might be an option.